# register_nav_menus with two wp_nav_menu for header and footer

Tags: wordpress

I create **wp_nav_menu** for my header and footer but its always return same menu intended only for footer.

**header**

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_locaiton' => 'Top',
        'menu_class' => 'top-side-navigation'           
        ) );
```

**footer**

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_locaiton' => 'Footer',
        'menu_class' => 'bottom-side-navigation'    
        ) );
```

and this is my **register** for my menu

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'Top' => __('Head Navigation'),
    'Footer' => __('Footer Selection'),
) );
```

I hoping to output for "Top" menu is
HOME, ABOUT, VISION, MISSION, CONTACT

and for the "Footer" is
ABOUT, VISION, MISSION, CONTACT

my problem is always return the "Footer" menu value
for "TOP" and "Footer"

Comment: Have you saved the menu items from the backend Appreance -> Menus ?

Comment: yes, i did. all was set up right at wordpress.

Comment: `'theme_location'`, not `'theme_locaiton'`

Comment: @Spartacus oh! my bad!!! yes thanks

Comment: I added this solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`'theme_location'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/), not `'theme_locaiton'`